# My mobile game gives a "Unfortunately stopped" working message on start

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, mobile-application

As I open my game application a message popped up saying "[app name] has Unfortunately stopped". The game works in unity and via the remote. but as soon as I build it and open it on my phone it stops working immediately.  Im using Unity 2017.4 (I use it because of more Monodevelop tutorials available). I have built similar games with the same process so I don't know what the issue is. Any thoughts on what might cause this.

It is built on the right android version for the phone I use and I have tried opening the same file on other phones to get the same error message with no real details.

The error "[app name] has unfortunately stopped" pops up on opening. I want the app/game to run when opened.

Comment: You won't know until you look in the logs, it could be anything.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Answer (score 0):

I updated the phone software and did a cleanup of any extra files, and cleared the backup files.I've noticed when my Samsung J3 runs low on memory it cuts out some functions, such as the syncing of emails or the functionality of certain apps. Turns out in this case it just refused to open a game file that required a lot of varied functions.